# pip install package in the same folder as the script

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I use Atom to create a Python Script, my script use some packages like requests, sendgrid and others..

To install this packages I use:

```
pip3 install requests
```

But this command install this package somewhere in windows, but my requirement is to package my script and this libraries to use them as an aws lambda.

My question: is there any way in Atom to package this with my script, or is there any command line to put this libraries in the same folder as my script and then I zip the folder? or what is the correct way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I find the solution in the [aws documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html):

I just used:

```
$ pip install --target 'C:\path-to-project\my-project' requests
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want to package this so you can use the package in the lambda function. This won't work if you've got a windows, because the Lambda function runs on a linux container (or sometimes it might work for pure python packages).

A more sustainable option is to use something like [Klayers](https://github.com/keithrozario/Klayers), you can set the preferred package as a layer for your function and it'll work.

Another option is to use the python serverless requirements package for the serverless framework. https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-python-requirements/

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use:

```
pip install --ignore-installed --install-option="--prefix=$YOUR-PATH" requests
```

The `--ignore-installed` flag is used to install other dependencies as well, even if those are already installed in the python packages folder.

Comment: What did you mean by  `YOUR-PATH` path of package of project?

Comment: The path to the folder where you have your script

Comment: I use `pip install --ignore-installed --install-option="--prefix='C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\MyProject'" requests` but I got an error `error: can't combine user with prefix, exec_prefix/home, or install_(plat)base`